# How to perform authentication on a SharePoint list?

Tags: list, jquery, authentication, spservices

I'm not exactly sure the process on how I can go about authenticating my web page for accessing a SharePoint list. Basically, I'm using the SPServices API, and I just need to read list data and display it in HTML.

However, I keep getting Access Denied because I have not authenticated.

What are the proper procedures (i.e. functions, syntax) for doing so?

Comment: Is this your SharePoint page? And can you post you current logic to see what could be wrong?

Comment: What are the permissions that you are having on sharepoint site and list?

Comment: It's not my SharePoint page. I'm trying to put all the information on an external HTML page, using SPServices (jQuery) to parse the data from my SharePoint list.

Comment: The permissions should be readable for any user, I believe.